# Hourly Pay Calc

Tags: c#

The Task:
Create a hourly pay calculator which is simple to use but effective.

```
    private double amount4Hours = 4;
    private double amount8Hours = 8;
    private double amount10Hours = 10;

    private void btnSubtotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double answer;
        // 45 min break removal
        double break45 = 0.75;

        double outputValue = 0;
        bool isNumber = true;
        //true false statement for error checking
        isNumber = double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue);
        isNumber = double.TryParse(text8Hours.Text, out outputValue);
        isNumber = double.TryParse(text10Hours.Text, out outputValue);
        if (!isNumber)
        {
            //error checking for blank text boxes
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a number from 0-9");
        }
        else
        {
            //calculates total amount of hours after breaks have been removed
            amount4Hours = amount4Hours * double.Parse(text4Hours.Text);

            amount8Hours = amount8Hours * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) - 
               break45 * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text);

            amount10Hours = amount10Hours * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text) - 
               break45 * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text);
            // Adds all together to output final amount of hours
            answer = amount4Hours + amount8Hours + amount10Hours;
            labSubtotal.Text = answer.ToString();
        }

    }

    private void btnPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hourly pay stored here
        double hourpay = 6.19;

        hourpay = hourpay * double.Parse(labSubtotal.Text);
        labPay.Text = hourpay.ToString();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Resets all text boxes back to blank
        text4Hours.Text = string.Empty;
        text8Hours.Text = string.Empty;
        text10Hours.Text = string.Empty;
        labSubtotal.Text = string.Empty;
        labPay.Text = string.Empty;


    }
}
```

}

The Problem...

- When I type in three different numbers in each text box, I get the outcome just perfect.
- If I hit the clear button, it does what I ask and removes everything from the output
- If I enter three numbers again (same ones or different ones) after it has been cleared, I will get different output.

I think it has something to do with the clear code because it's not resetting the values to zero like it does at the start of the program. I have tried setting the clear code to input zeros, but that doesn't help; just gives the same problem.

Comment: Something which will probably be more useful to you than solving your problem for you: http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282  This section is on learning how to debug.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid text not directly related to a problem (like "new here", "searched a lot", "thank you") and tags (like "C#") in the title in future posts. If you want to add details about yourself - edit you user info instead. Also try to format your code in shorter lines to avoid horizontal scroll...

Comment: You may want to use "decimal" instead of "double," double has rounding errors while decimal does not.  It is common practice to use decimal for money-related storage where accuracy is necessary.

Comment: You need to and `isNumber` with each `TryParse` after the first one.  Otherwise you are only checking if `text10Hours.Text` is numeric and not all of them.  Like this `isNumber &= double.TryParse....`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case to show how to use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on the line:

```
amount4Hours = amount4Hours * double.Parse(text4Hours.Text);
```

Then when you calculate the answer, watch how the `amount4Hours` variable changes.

This type of bug shows why people avoid the use of global variables.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response and I'm a little annoyed at myself over the global variables and how i didn't think about that. will defo take a look at the debugger and I'm going to have a quick read over global variables info just to make sure i understand better and stop this mistake happening again.

Answer (score 1):

```
private double amount4Hours = 4;
private double amount8Hours = 8;
private double amount10Hours = 10;
```

This code should go into your ***btnSubtotal_Click***.

Comment: Private isn't necessary due to encapsulation, but this is the correct answer (as it uses proper object-oriented design). I'll reiterate as well that when dealing with money, decimal should be used instead of double.

Comment: True. private is unnecessary due to encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
amount4Hours = 4;
amount8Hours = 8;
amount10Hours = 10;
```

Put this code in clear button. You also need to reset your global variables.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, on a general point you need to use the debugger for figuring out why something hasn't worked as you expected. In this case you are creating 3 global variables at the beginning (amount4hours etc.) and then manipulating them later on when clicking btnSubmit. At no point when btnClear do you reset your global values. Try adding in your btnClear_Click method:

```
amount4hours = 4;
amount8hours = 8;
amount10hours = 10;
```

This will reset your global variables.

Answer (score 0):

If the global variables value should not be updated,why not directly get the value of answer by having their sum value directly

```
/*amount4Hours = amount4Hours * double.Parse(text4Hours.Text);
* 
* amount8Hours = amount8Hours * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) -
*                  break45 * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text);
*                  
* amount10Hours = amount10Hours * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text) -
*                  break45 * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text);
*                  
* answer = amount4Hours + amount8Hours + amount10Hours;*/
answer = amount4Hours * double.Parse(text4Hours.Text) +
         amount8Hours * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) - 
            break45 * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) +
         amount10Hours * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text) -
            break45 * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text);
```

By the way, your error checking is fail because you stored all checking result in same variable therefore only the third textbox content is checked based on your logic. I assume you display the MessageBox whenever one of three textbox have invalid input. Then,

```
        //bool isNumber = true;
        //true false statement for error checking
        //isNumber = double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue);
        //isNumber = double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue);;
        //isNumber = double.TryParse(text10Hours.Text, out outputValue);
        //if (!isNumber)
        if (!double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue)||
            !double.TryParse(text8Hours.Text, out outputValue)||
            !double.TryParse(text10Hours.Text, out outputValue))
        {
            //error checking for blank text boxes
            //the checking only check if they are double type
            //but not checking the range from 0 to 9
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a number from 0-9");
        }
```